# Alternate text for empty UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using a UITableView to display some data which the user can filter. If a certain (perfectly "legal") combination is selected, **all** data is filtered out (hidden). I would like to display some text stating that no results were found and to please modify your filters.

Does anything trigger when this occurs that I can hook in to?

Or will I have to manually check for an empty data set and create a custom view to display my text? (I was thinking of creating a blank cell and using that footer? Hoping for something more elegant...)

I found a similar question, but the solution is not what I am looking for: [Handling empty UITableView in UITableViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490225/handling-empty-uitableview-in-uitableviewcontrollera)

Also, I have an Android programming background and use this exact feature frequently, I would be surprised if Apple didn't do this as well!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Put a custom view with your error text message behind the table. Then when there is no data to be displayed set table.alpha=0.0 (or table.hidden=YES), while when you have this data available set table.alpha=1.0 (or table.hidden=NO).
You can do the control on the "OK" button (or equivalent) of the filter.

Comment: In fact UITableView has a property backgroundView that you can use exactly for this purpose.  No need to fiddle with the alpha or hidden properties.

Comment: When using UITableViewController, it easier to use the backgroundView as @RayFix suggested and add a custom label/view. But you might need to change the tableView.separatorStyle to UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone, and restore it when state changes.